# Is the default behavior with Fluent NHibernate to lazy load HasMany<T> collections?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

when I am setting up my fluent mappings, what is the default for collections? Do I need to explicitly set them as lazy-load, or is that the default?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note this is changed as of current day to be inline with NHibernate standards which is lazy loading is enabled by default for everything.