# Fluent NHibernate List of objects exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a DAL using Fluent NHibernate for mapping a query (stored in db as strings) and their parameters (stored in a separate table).

When I try to use this list of parameters in the service layer, I run into problems.

```
List<QueryParameter> lqp = (List<QueryParameter>)qry.parameters;
```

**Throws**

> Unable to cast object of type Hibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[nha.cs.utility.mole.QueryParameter]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [nha.cs.utility.mole.QueryParameter]'.

```
List<QueryParameter> lqp = qry.parameters.ToList<QueryParameter>();
```

**Throws**

> Initializing[nha.cs.utility.mole.Query#24]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: nha.cs.utility.mole.Query.parameters, no session or session was closed

```
List<QueryParameter> lqp = new List<QueryParameter>(qry.parameters);
```

**Throws**

> Test method MoleSVSTest.MoleSVCTester.MoleSVCTestMethod threw exception: 
>       NHibernate.LazyInitializationException:
>   Initializing[nha.cs.utility.mole.Query#24]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: nha.cs.utility.mole.Query.parameters, no session or session was closed

```
IList<QueryParameter> lqp = (IList<QueryParameter>)qry.parameters;
```

**Throws**

> Test method MoleSVSTest.MoleSVCTester.MoleSVCTestMethod threw exception: 
>   NHibernate.LazyInitializationException: Initializing[nha.cs.utility.mole.Query#24]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: nha.cs.utility.mole.Query.parameters, no session or session was closed

```
public class Query
{
    public virtual int id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    public virtual string query { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<QueryParameter> parameters { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Application> applicationsUsedIn { get; set; }

    public Query()
    {
        this.parameters = new List<QueryParameter>();
        this.applicationsUsedIn = new List<Application>();
    }

    public virtual void AddParameter(QueryParameter qp)
    {
        qp.query = this;
        this.parameters.Add(qp);
    }
}
```

```
public class QueryMap : ClassMap<Query>
{
    public QueryMap()
    {
        Table("dbo.Queries");
        Id(x => x.id);
        Map(x => x.name);
        Map(x => x.query);
        HasMany(x => x.parameters)
            .Cascade.All()
            .KeyColumn("qryid")
            .LazyLoad()
            ;
        HasManyToMany(x => x.applicationsUsedIn)
            .Table("dbo.ApplicationsQueries")
            .ParentKeyColumn("qryid")
            .ChildKeyColumn("appid")
            .Inverse()
            .LazyLoad()
            ;
    }
}
```

```
    public XmlNode runQuery(string appnname, string qryname, List<String> parms)
    {
        XmlNode xn = null;

        if ((null != appnname) && (appnname.Length > 0))
        {
            if ((null != qryname) && (qryname.Length > 0))
            {
                Query qry = md.getQuery(appnname, qryname);
                if (null != qry)
                {
                    if ((null != parms) && (parms.Count > 0)) //Passed parameters as List<String>
                    {
                        //These are the three lines I have tried
                        IList<QueryParameter> lqp = (IList<QueryParameter>)qry.parameters;
                        List<QueryParameter> lqp = qry.parameters.ToList<QueryParameter>();
                        List<QueryParameter> lqp = new List<QueryParameter>(qry.parameters);
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

**Updated with QueryParameter class and map.**

```
public class QueryParameter
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual Query query { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    public virtual MOLEDataTypes type { get; set; }
    public virtual int order { get; set; }

    public QueryParameter()
    {
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as QueryParameter;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (query == t.query && name == t.name)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (query.id + "|" + name).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

```
public class QueryParametersMap : ClassMap<QueryParameter>
{
    public QueryParametersMap()
    {
        Table("dbo.QueryParameters");
        Id(x => x.id);
        References(x => x.query).Column("qryid").Not.Insert();
        Map(x => x.name);
        Map(x => x.type).CustomType<MOLEDataTypes>();
        Map(x => x.order).Column("ordr");
    }
}
```

**More Code**

```
    public Query getQuery(string appname, string qryname)
    {
        Query retq = null;

        using (ISessionFactory isf = getSessionFactory())
        {
            using (var sess = isf.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var tran = sess.Transaction)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        tran.Begin();
                        ...
                        USING session
                        ...
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        tran.Rollback();
                        sess.Close();
                        lws.logMessage(AppName, "getQuery", ex.ToString(), MessageType.Error, MessageLevel.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (retq);
    }
```

Any hints or suggestions you might have would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Bruce.

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using? And can you please provide your entity/mapping for `QueryParameter` too?

Comment: I added the classes as you suggested.

Comment: Actually, that wasn't necessary. I'm not sure what I was thinking. Anyway, I believe your problem lies with your session. Do you close/clear your session when you call `md.getQuery()`? Or are you wrapping the `getQuery()` method in a `using (session)` block? If so, then that's most probably the cause of your error. Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893611/nhibernate-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role

Comment: I am using a session at the DAL level, opening and closing in the getQuery method. Are you saying that I need to keep that session open for the time that I am using the result of the getQuery method. Which is a Query object.

Comment: I added the getQuery method. Is the way that I am using the session here not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you close the session in `getQuery`, and then ask for the list of parameters for your `Query` object, which NHibernate tries to load and fails due to the absence of a session. To solve your problem, you need to ensure that your session is open throughout the request, or at least remains open until all business transactions have completed.

I would suggest that you take a session-per-request approach. Open a session whenever there's a web request, and close it when the session ends. This can be achieved easily by using the Global.asax file, which you can read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{    
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }  

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a session factory when the application starts.
        // Session factories are expensive to create, and therefore you should create one and use it throughout your application.
        SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                                 .Database(
                                    SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
                                        .UsingFile("firstProject.db")
                                 )
                                 .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a session per request.
        var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the session at the end of every request
        var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
        session.Dispose();
    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the session factory at the end of the application.
        if (SessionFactory != null)
            SessionFactory.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In the example above, a session factory is created when the application starts, which is recommended because it is costly to create a session factory. Then, a session is created every request, and disposed at the end. By using this approach, you save yourself a lot of work since everything is done automatically.

Then, to use a session in your code, you would just need to call `GetCurrentSession()`, like so:

```
var session = Global.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
```

I hope that helps, and best of luck fiddling with NHibernate. I would suggest you to consider reading the [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book) for a better understanding of NHibernate.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. You were correct. Once I altered my code to create and maintain the session in the service layer, the problem was solved.